# php - how do I lowercase this string?

Tags: php

I have this code that pulls up a name and will link to the page of my website associated with that name. The problem is that it links to something like MyPage, instead of mypage - which doesn't work. how do I lowercase 'name' in just the link? (I hope that made sense)

```
<a href="/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?>
```

Comment: The **first** result in Google, when searching for *"php - how do I lowercase this string?"* is... http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtolower` function like this:

```
<a href="/<?php echo strtolower($row['name']); ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Omg, I feel so dumb. I had tried that but forgot the parenthesis. *facepalm* - thank you!!

Comment: hahaha ...."facepalm"....that was funny, lol!